# Calculated field doesn't seem to be grouping correctly

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset which looks somewhat like this;

```
email       minutes   date
aaa@aaa.com   40      10-01-18

aaa@aaa.com   60      10-01-18

bbb@bbb.com   10      10-01-18

bbb@bbb.com   40      10-02-18

ccc@ccc.com   60      10-02-18
```

I have created a calculated field to group the `minutes` by `date`, per `email`. This calculated field is named 'Minutes Worked' and looks like so;

```
 {FIXED [email], [date] : SUM([minutes])}
```

I wish to visualize "complete days" which would be `Minutes Worked` > 80. Here's what I did;

1. `YEAR(date) MONTH(date)` on columns.
2. `SUM(Number of Records)` on rows.
3. `SUM(Number of Records)` on text.
4. `Minutes Worked` > 80 on filter.

The problem is that the viz seems to be looking at each row for `minutes` rather than the grouping per day. I thought my calculated field would handle this but it doesn't seem to be the case. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about how the Fixed LODs work. Fixed LODs are independent of your view. Without the filter, your data will be as below.
[image]

If you apply the filter, then here is the data in the view
[image]

There is only a single user who meets the criteria, but there are two records. Based on your description, here is your view which is correct based on the conditions applied.
[image]
 You need a different logic to find what you want. If you are looking for number of users who worked more than 80 minutes per day, you can use below calculation, but be mindfull that it is independent of your view. So if you change your view, you might need to change your calculations. [This link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) might be helpful to understand LODs.

```
   IF  [Minutes Worked] > 80 
        THEN {FIXED [Email],[Date]:COUNTD([Email])} 
        ELSE 0
    END
```